# How to create a report scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks

A user can choose (and continually edit) which days they want to receive certain reports:

```
3 report options
7 possible days (Monday - Sunday)
```

If a user can receive any of the 3 reports on any day of the week, or at the end of the month, what is the best way to store the data in the database?

```
User 1's report schedule = report 1 monday and tuesday, report 2 monday, report 3 at the end of every month
```

My first thought was to use a Schedule model and have boolean values but it soon got out of control:

```
Schedule model
attr_accessible  :report_one_monday, :report_one_tuesday, :report_one_wednesday, :report_one_thursday, :report_one_friday, :report_one_saturday, :report_one_sunday
:report_two_monday, :report_two_tuesday, :report_two_wednesday, :report_two_thursday, :report_two_friday, :report_two_saturday, :report_two_sunday
:report_three_monday, :report_three_tuesday, :report_three_wednesday, :report_three_thursday, :report_three_friday, :report_three_saturday, :report_three_sunday
:report_one_end_of_month etc
```

I want to use heroku scheduler to run a rake task daily to see which reports it must send. The end of the month task would look something like:

```
task :send_reports => :environment do
 if Date.today == Date.today.end_of_month
  Business.where(report_one_end_of_month: true).each do |business|
   MyMailer.send_month_end_report(business).deliver
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) which is super set of refus scheduler.

We are using this tool to generate reports in background and email it to user from long time which will definitely solve your problem.

Resque is the redis based tool to run background jobs and resque-scheduler is of course scheduler, which can accept cron schedule to schedule the resque job in future.